# MongoDB remote connection

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB for remote connection. First I tried localhost and internal ip address to build the connection. Both of them succeeded. Then I tried external ip address to connect on my own computer of MAC as an experiment first. I have created an admin user for the database in MongoDB. The bind_ip option is also commented in mongodb.conf. The firewall should also have been turned down. But the connection cannot been built still. Does anyone know the reason?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To allow connecting remote clients (which is your case) to MongoDB Server.

Make sure to do set bind_ip to either of values,  in your `mongodb.conf` file -

Following is with any IP

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

Following for bind to specific IP

```
bind_ip = 10.52.36.99 (or any specific  IP)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this. My goal is to connect to the database from external network. And I can use internal ip address to connect. But the external ip address failed. I tried this in the same computer. Maybe I should user two different computers?

Comment: Three years on, I am trying this but doesn't seem to work. can you help me with it? Still no hit. bind_ip in the conf file has both localhost and the host ip address. I am doing this on CentOS.